# How to clear memory in 2.3.4 like I did in 2.2.1

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

In 2.2.1, all I have to do to clear the RAM on the device is long tap the home key, then choose task manager and then go to the RAM manager to clear the RAM.  I'm finding that this has been changed in 2.3.4.  How do I clear the devices RAM in 2.3.4?  The device that I have is the Nexus One.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Nexus One, clarified in question

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the "Task Manager" menu on an AOSP/"Google Experience" device...Was the 2.2.1 device also the Nexus One and you upgraded, or was it a different device?

Comment: The task manager I saw was on a Samsung Epic, so I'm guessing its proprietary to that device.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a TouchWiz thing. I have it on my Fascinate, for example, but not my EVO (2.3.4) or an Android emulator (2.2).

Comment: You shouldn't have to clear memory in latest Android versions.  The OS itself is quite good at killing tasks that are no longer needed to make room for newly executed apps and services.

Comment: Well I am testing an application I'm writing that involves a repeating task that persists after the application is finished so I would like to just clear the RAM as it would be the easiest way to get rid of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous Task Manager was a Samsung addition, and not part of Android itself.

In 2.3 onwards there's a very similar and memory usage listing. If you go into Settings, then into Applications and click the "Running Services" option, it should show you everything that's running along with how much memory it's using. There's also a small graph at the bottom showing RAM used vs RAM free.

Comment: I had seen this, but looking around there was no immediate way to kill processes or clear memory, that I saw.

Comment: @Styler if you click a non-core app in the Running list don't you get a "Stop" button for it and it's child processes?

Comment: Ok, before I swore I clicked on it and nothing happened. I get to that screen now, wow. Thanks!